# Why does scala map java.lang.Object parameters of java-defined methods to scala.Any?

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

Given a Java class

```
public class Test {
  public static int foo(Object o) {
    return 10;
  }
}
```

The Scala compiler maps the parameter type `Object` to `scala.Any`:

```
scala> Test.foo _
res0: Any => Int = <function1>
```

I guess the reason is to allow passing Scala primitives (like `true`) to such functions, which may be desirable in many situations. Any important examples?

```
scala> Test.foo(true)
res1: Int = 10
```

Here's a kind of counter-example:

```
scala> val h = 1000
h: Int = 1000

scala> System.identityHashCode(h) == System.identityHashCode(h)
res8: Boolean = false
```

Defining a similar method in Scala gives a type mismatch (the error message is a bit confusing, but in the end, `Int <: AnyVal` does not conform to `Object` / `AnyRef`).

```
scala> def foo(o: Object) = 10
foo: (o: Object)Int

scala> foo(true)
<console>:9: error: the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
              foo(true)
                  ^
```

Comment: Might have something to do with the fact that every type in scala is a class, even `Int`. The scala compiler chooses to use the primitive as often as it can behind the scenes, but makes the class available from start

Comment: Yes, and `Any` is a super type of every type.

Answer (score 2):

It could be partly historical, anyway, here's my 2 cents:

- Scala has *unified generics*, so primitive types can be used to instantiate a generic type (for instance, `List[Int]`). When compiling `List[A]`, `A` can stand for a primitive as well as a reference type, but after erasure all signatures mentioning `A` are replaced by  (the erasure of) its upper bound. That is `Object` (there is no better option on the JVM).

  If you go the other way around, what should be the Scala type associated to `Object`? Of course, erasure is not bijective, but it seems a good idea to map it back to `Any`. This allows Scala generic types to be passed to Java code expecting `Object`. Before Java generics (Scala existed before Java 1.5), this was a very useful feature (among others, to use Java collections).
- universal equality. This allows the use of `==` on generic types (which can be primitives, so it needs to use `Any` in its signature). Universal equality has its drawbacks, but I doubt we could live without it on the JVM.